# Excel component with charts for Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, components, xls

I was using a company called ActiveXLS to save native XLS files with charts from Classic ASP but they seem to have closed down.

Can anyone recommend an alternative classic asp excel component I can use?

CSV or HTML (with XLS content type) export is not sufficient for what I need.

Comment: Is this for Excel 2003 or 2007?   Can you consider using an ASP.NET component and passing the data between Classic ASP and ASP.NET?  It is not difficult to write a .NET component that can be called from ASP

Comment: Possibly, does this require passing some kind of session key using the database to make it work or is there a simpler way than that?  I don't really know anything about .net technology.

Comment: If you wanted to pass it via the database you could.  Or you can create a .NET program that will take parameters on a query line and generate the appropriate XLS chart for you.  Do you want to generate worksheets with data and charts (lots of query paramter size) or just a chart (i.e. ASP does the work of calculating, and simply passes parameters to an ASP.NET page that generates the worksheet and chart)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the MS Excel DOM using Classic ASP.  There are definite limitations of this approach for a web based environment but I have used it for low volumes.

Here's some sample code to illustrate:

```
Set oApp = Server.CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Add
Set oSheet = oBook.ActiveSheet
Set oRange = oApp.ActiveCell

' Create the header fields
oRange.Cells(1,1) = "Column 1"
oRange.Cells(1,2) = "Column 2"

oSheet.Range(oSheet.Cells(1,1), oSheet.Cells(i,j)).Select
oApp.Selection.Columns.AutoFit
oSheet.Cells(1,1).Select

oBook.SaveAs "filename.xls"
oBook.Close
oApp.Quit

Set oApp = Nothing
```

This does require Excel to be installed on the server that builds these files.